# Full screen Chromium but no remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-x-session

I've followed this guide to set up a Kiosk pc:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/

Small difference is that I did it all with the admin account and I didn't use the xscreensaver because the pc is used as a monitoring device ( loads an internal webpage which shows all webserver states etc ).

The only problem I have now is that while I'm in the kiosk mode session I can't access the pc with remote VNC. I tried adding a command to manually start vinoserver in the kiosk shell but to no avail.

As I'm fairly new to this I hope you can help me.

You probably need more information, but I'm unsure what you need, so please just tell me whatever info I can provide and I'll add it asap.

EDIT: As an additional question, I'm unable to prevent the system from going to standby even though the normal gnome session is set to always on. Any help on that account would also be welcome

Thanks!

Comment: As is described in the article I'm using ubuntu 10.04. A kiosk PC is a system only running a browser on a single webpage usually. Mostly used for narrowcasting or monitor systems or slideshows etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X2go should help with that.

I have added some answer for basic remote desktop, but you can try it just for an application (it has that support)

Please check my answer here:

[Remote desktop for multiple users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247115/remote-desktop-for-multiple-users/287371#287371)

X2go and ssh Works with better support and features for linux remote desktop. (Like, file sharing, clipboard sharing, sound over net, web client, etc).